# What is the maximum time series data required for ARIMA and ANN modelling?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, arima

I have a per hour data in 1 year for a total of 8,640 observations. These data will be used to model ARIMA and ANN to predict a day-ahead forecast. My question is, is these data enough? or too much?